# Modify max_length for a field in an abstract model

Tags: python, django

```
class AbstractBaseField(models.Model):
    choices = models.CharField(_("Choices"), max_length=1000, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class TicketField(AbstractBaseField):
    pass

TicketField._meta.get_field("choices").max_length = 5000
```

I'm trying to modify the `max_length` attribute on a field on `TicketField`, which inherits from an abstract model. As you see, I've monkey-patched the field on model definition and the migration is generated as expected. The field has the `max_length` applied correctly and I can set the value just fine via the shell, but admin validation fails as if the old `max_length` is still present, showing the error *Ensure this value has at most 1000 characters (it has XXXX)*.

I've inspected the `max_length` on the ModelForm and the Validator values at runtime, and they all use the new `max_length`, but somehow a validation error is still being raised.

```
(Pdb) self.fields["choices"].max_length
5000
(Pdb) self.fields["choices"].validators[0]._constructor_args
((5000,), {})
(Pdb) self.fields["choices"].widget.attrs
{u'class': u'vTextField', u'maxlength': '5000'}
```